# JSP isn't executed by Tomcat when IP Address is used instead of 'localhost', showing Source Code

Tags: jsp, localhost, tomcat7, ip-address

JSP Isn't executed by Tomcat in the same machine where is installed.

I have my code test like other post to be simpler:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
Hello!  The time is now <%= new java.util.Date() %>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

With **Local IP** I have:

[image: JSP Is Not Executing]

Now testing with **localhost**:

[image: JSP Is Executing]

Verifying **httpd.conf** of Apache:

```
Include "C:/.../Httpd/conf/auto/mod_jk.conf"
```

Inside of **mod_jk.conf** of Tomcat:

```
...
JkWorkersFile "C:/.../Tomcat/conf/jk/workers.properties"
...
<VirtualHost localhost>
  ServerName localhost
  ...
  JkMount /*.jsp  ajp13
</VirtualHost>
```

I think that is possible mistake in settings of **workers.properties**:

```
# BEGIN workers.properties
# Definition for Ajp13 worker
worker.list=ajp13
worker.ajp13.port=8009
worker.ajp13.host=localhost
worker.ajp13.type=ajp13
# END workers.properties
```

Maybe worker.ajp13.host=**localhost** is the problem.

But' I need to know how to change localhost enabled to be used by my LAN.

Answer (score 0):

No, your problem is in the Apache configuration. It is forwarding requests to AJP only for the localhost interface. You should repeat the configuration for the 192.168.97.24 interface.

Apache does not understand that it should forward the request from 192.168.97.24 to AJP, so it is serving the plain file.

Comment: But, where I change this in httpd.conf? or a new Virtualhost in mod_jk.conf?

Comment: I am not an Apache expert; the least thing you should do is repeat the `<VirtualHost localhost>` stuff but as `<VirtualHost 192.168.97.24>`. There may be better ways to do that, but this a quick and dirty solution to verify the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was:

```
...
JkWorkersFile "C:/.../Tomcat/conf/jk/workers.properties"
...
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ...
  JkMount /*.jsp ajp13
</VirtualHost>
```